# Protractor "It" spec fails when Element is not found

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

```
Here is the code: 


    it('Verify Backup details if present', function(){
    (profile_page.BPP_Contact_BackupDiv).isPresent().then(function(isVisible){
 if (isVisible) {
                expect((profile_page.BPP_Contact_Backup).getText()).toEqual("Backup:");
                expect((profile_page.BPP_Contact_BackupData).getText()).not.toBe(null);
                expect((profile_page.BPP_Contact_BackupData).getAttribute("href")).not.toBe(null);
            } else{
             console.log("BPP_Contact_BackupDiv Is not Displayed");
              }
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("In Error");
            console.log(err);
              });
    });
```

As far as I have understand this should go in "If" the element is present and "Else" if element is not.
I am following Page object modal and 
BPP_Contact_BackupDiv = element(by.css(my element identifier));
this is failing when element is not present. 
I am getting this Error : 
-Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specification by jasmine.Default_Timeout_Interval

I have also tried this in Before Each:

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('inside timeout');
        done();
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you would use [`browser.isElementPresent()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.isElementPresent) instead:

```
browser.isElementPresent(profile_page.BPP_Contact_BackupDiv).then(...)
```

Comment: HI alec, Sorry for late reply, I tried it.  It is still failing with same error. .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that issue got resolved when i added a time out more than what i gave as default time out:

```
it('Verify Backup details if present', function(){
    (profile_page.BPP_Contact_BackupDiv).isPresent().then(function(isVisible){
 if (isVisible) {
                expect((profile_page.BPP_Contact_Backup).getText()).toEqual("Backup:");
                expect((profile_page.BPP_Contact_BackupData).getText()).not.toBe(null);
                expect((profile_page.BPP_Contact_BackupData).getAttribute("href")).not.toBe(null);
            } else{
             console.log("BPP_Contact_BackupDiv Is not Displayed");
              }
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("In Error");
            console.log(err);
              });
    }60000);
```